# Return matching check dates for employees but getting previous check dates that match the gross amount of the checks SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, case-when

I am trying to display the payroll date for employees who have received a check on the most current check date. However, when I enter the following, it is returning employees multiple times if the amount of their check matches a previous check. Shouldn't this be returning dates that match the current check date as opposed to also returning previous check dates with the same gross pay?

```
        WHEN ext.TerminationDate IS NULL AND @CheckDate = f.CheckDate THEN format(@CheckDate,'yyyyMMdd')
```

`f` is a table I am pulling the dates from and `@checkdate` is a parameter. Anyone know what is causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

From the way you have your WHEN statement set up, it looks like you have this set up as a column in the SELECT statement. If that is where this sits, then your script is not really filtering out anything. You are simply checking if the current row matches your variable and then passing your variable (once formatted) back.

This is how I would look at forming your query:

```
select OtherColums, format(f.CheckDate, 'yyyyMMdd') from f where f.CheckDate = @CheckDate
```

This will filter out to only records that have checkDate columns equal to your variable. If this does not help, please provide more information because the code you provided does not give us much context.